# How to set start and end of profiling on Valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

To create the profile dump on valgrind, one does:

valgrind --tool=callgrind program [program_options]

[from http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html ]

I would like to set the start and end of the profiling within some source files.  For example

start main.cpp:30 
stop main.cpp:44

I think of this having profiled using this technique on Android.  Is this possible on Valgrind ?

Comment: Is that a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference manual http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.basics you are at least able to start and stop profiling by your own client request:

> If the program section you want to profile is somewhere in the middle of the run, it is beneficial to fast forward to this section without any profiling, and then enable profiling. This is achieved by using the command line option --instr-atstart=no and running, in a shell: callgrind_control -i on just before the interesting code section is executed. To exactly specify the code position where profiling should start, use the client request CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cr.start-instr

> CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION
>   Start full Callgrind instrumentation if not already enabled. When cache simulation is done, this will flush the simulated cache and lead to an artifical cache warmup phase afterwards with cache misses which would not have happened in reality. See also option --instr-atstart.
>
> CALLGRIND_STOP_INSTRUMENTATION
>   Stop full Callgrind instrumentation if not already disabled. This flushes Valgrinds translation cache, and does no additional instrumentation afterwards: it effectivly will run at the same speed as Nulgrind, i.e. at minimal slowdown. Use this to speed up the Callgrind run for uninteresting code parts. Use CALLGRIND_START_INSTRUMENTATION to enable instrumentation again. See also option --instr-atstart.